# How to express probability in the future (either through verb conjugation or adverbs)?

Tags: traducción, verbos, conjugación, solicitud-de-término, adverbios

I want to translate the following sentence into Spanish:

> It will likely be seen by more interested people.

Consider that `it` refers to `el mensaje` in the context and since it's a masculine name, I've used `él` in its translation.
And to express possibility in the future, I've used future subjunctive (I wanna see if this is true?)
So based on the [conjugation of the Spanish verb ser](http://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/ser), the translation of `it will likely be` can be something like `él fuere`, then

> it will likely be seen == él fuere visto

And the translation of the first sentence will be:

> él fuere visto por mas gente interesados.

Are my conclusions true?
Generally how should we express the probability or possibility in the future (because as you know `likely` is an English adverb that shows probability) in Spanish language?

Comment: Subjunctive would require a subordinate clause first that for one reason or another would be in the future (which is never obligated in modern Spanish): "será posible que el mensaje fuere visto", but unless you're someone like me (lol), you would go with much simpler structures.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb: never use the future subjunctive in Spanish. Nobody does, really. Just use the future indicative along with an adverb indicating the level of certainty you have about the subject:

> El mensaje será visto probablemente por gente más interesada. (Fair level of certainty.)
>
> El mensaje será visto seguramente por gente más interesada. (High level of certainty.)

You can insert "probablemente" after or before "será visto", or even in the middle ("será probablemente visto"). You can even use the active voice instead of the passive one:

> El mensaje lo verá gente más interesada, probablemente.

Yes, you can also put the adverb at the end.

Comment: "Nobody does, really." Contradiré al que dijere algo así, ofreciéndome como ejemplo. :-)

Comment: @guifa so what do you suggest for the translation of `Please share or like the post as much as possible. This will help it be seen on more news feeds and it will likely be seen by more interested people.` What do you think about this? `Haz el favor compartid o gustad el mensaje todo lo posible. Esto lo ayudará ser visto en más últimas noticias y Es probable que sea visto por gente más interesada.`. You know I'm completely illiterate in spanish and I'm not learning right now. I'm just struggling to do some translations. (Carlos wasn't mentioned, because he'll be notified any way)

Comment: @sepideh note that the whole sentence changes the verb. If you want to say "this will help it be seen..." then you must use the subjunctive in the relative clause: "esto ayudará a que sea visto..." In fact, my whole answer would change as I would say "ayudará a que pueda ser visto por más gente interesada", and express the probability with "pueda" (could).

Comment: @guifa es nuestro personaje venido del [Ministerio del tiempo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_ministerio_del_tiempo) :-D

Comment: So you mean the good translation for `Please share or like the post as much as possible. This will help it be seen on more news feeds and it will likely be seen by more interested people.` would be `Has el favor compratid o gustad el mensaje todo lo posible. Esto ayudará a que sea visto en más últimas noticias y ayudará a que pueda ser visto por más gente interesada.` @guifa

Comment: you know I'm not learning spanish right now and i'm just struggling to translate some short sentences. So i'm more interested in the final correct answer. (I know it's a big request and I really appreciate if you help). [There's just one more short sentence in the chat that I need it's translation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32834352#32834352). Will you help me in this final step? @fedorqui (carlos not mentioned because he'll be notified any way)

Comment: @sepideh you know this site is for Spanish-language learners, and it is not intended to be a bulk translation service. You are supposed to learn from the answers to the questions. By now you should be able to translate the last part all by yourself. In order to translate the rest, some other questions may be needed, such as "What is the Spanish expression for news feed?" or "What is the Spanish equivalent to 'like the post' as an order?" as we don't usually use the imperative in verbs such as "gustar".

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Total certainty

> **It will be seen** by more interested people
>
> **Será visto** por gente más     interesada

### 2. Fair level of certainty

> **It will likely be seen** by more interested people
>
> **Es probable que sea visto**  por gente más interesada

Another form:

> **It could be seen** by more interested people.
>
> **Podría ser visto** por gente más interesada

### 3. Low level of certainty

> **It might be seen** by more interested people
>
> **Podría ser visto** por gente más interesada

In english *could* has higher level of certainty than *might*, but in spanish there's no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You'd express probability by using the phrase "es probable que" combined with either the present subjunctive ([to indicate uncertainty](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/es-probable-que-subjunctive-indicative.159629/)) or future. The future subjunctive (which you are using there) is [not in common use anymore](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/100059/future-subjunctive#.V_v9v6PMyt8). Therefore:

"Es probable que gente más interesada lo verán"

You have the right idea though - in most other cases you'd express probability using a variety of different verb tenses/moods.

Answer (score 1):

Sin la palabra **likely**, traducirías la frase como:

> Será visto por más personas interesadas. (o más gente interesada)

Para expresar **likelihood**, podrías usar varias palabras:

> Probablemente será visto por más personas interesadas.
>
> Es probable que sea visto por...
>
> Es posible que sea visto por...
>
> Puede que sea visto por...
>
> Puede ser que lo vea mucha gente interesada.
>
> A lo mejor será visto por...
>
> etc.

El subjuntivo **"fuere"** no cabe en este caso. Pero si se *qusiere* expresar incertidumbre, se podría decir:

> Si el mensaje *fuere* visto por muchas personas, nuestra campaña *pudiere* ser exitosa.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the explanations are in spanish. It will be hard for a beginner to understand.